# Invoke a REST service from PL/SQL – make an HTTP get request using UTL_HTTP in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

Getting the error , please help us to set the rest API service. When we try to invoke the REST API to fetch the data by GET request facing the below http error.

```
--
DECLARE
    login         INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    sec           INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    req           utl_http.req;
    resp          utl_http.resp;
    l_clob        CLOB;
    l_text        VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR);
    l_key         VARCHAR2(550);
    l_dg          CHAR(50);
    l_url         VARCHAR2(200);
    l_host        VARCHAR2(550);
    l_port        NUMBER;
    l_user        VARCHAR2(550);
    l_passwd      VARCHAR2(550);
    l_wallet_path VARCHAR2(550);
    l_wallet_pwd  VARCHAR2(550);

BEGIN

    l_wallet_path := '/tmp/wallet';
    l_wallet_pwd := 'sample_tes123';
    l_url := 'https://rest api // sample test';
    l_accesskey := 'asefevhefvfvkfekv;efv;';
    utl_http.set_wallet(l_wallet_path, l_wallet_pwd);
    dbms_output.put_line('wallet set');
    req := utl_http.begin_request(l_url, 'GET', utl_http.http_version_1_1);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_url);
    /* Stablish the Authentication */               
    --utl_http.set_authentication( req ,l_datagroup ,l_accesskey);
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'Authorization', l_accesskey);
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'login', 0);
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'sec', 0);
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'VIN', '12345');
    dbms_output.put_line('header set');
    resp := utl_http.get_response(req);
    IF resp.status_code != 200 THEN
        utl_http.end_response(resp);
        utl_http.end_request(req);
        RETURN;
    END IF;

    BEGIN
        dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, TRUE);
        LOOP
            utl_http.read_text(resp, l_text, 1000);
            dbms_output.put_line(l_text || chr(10));
            dbms_lob.writeappend(l_clob, length(l_text), l_text);
            l_text := NULL;
        END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
            utl_http.end_response(resp);
            utl_http.end_request(req);
            dbms_output.put_line('error!!!');
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('error!!!');
            RETURN;
    END;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
        utl_http.end_response(resp);
        utl_http.end_request(req);
        dbms_output.put_line('error!!!');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        utl_http.end_response(resp);
        utl_http.end_request(req);
        dbms_output.put_line('error!!!' || sqlerrm);
END;

/

/**/
```

Getting error :

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1530
ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1470
ORA-06512: at line 1
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the output of `get_detailed_sqlerrm`.

Comment: The error is `operation timed out` which could be caused by many things including: the server not being able to reach the internet; the destination server being off-line; or, among other reasons, simply that the request does take a long time to respond and you aren't waiting long enough and need to increase the time-out.